# Stop playing video in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have on form WebBrowser component. For example, has launched a website and playing video. Is it possible to programmatically stop playing( downloading, as if clicked the Stop button on the player.)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could navigate through the HtmlElements in the WebBrowser to press this button. I know this is possible with submitting forms etc, so you should be able to do this.